# Multiple join in Supabase JS

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have 3 tables in supabase.

- Message --> with foreign key 'request_id' to table Product_Request
- Product_Request --> with foreign key 'product_id' to table Product
- Product

How can i select all messages data with info from the others table?

I tried this:

`let { data, error } = await supabase .from("message") .select("*, product_request(*), product(*)");`

but give me this error:

`{    "details": "Searched for a foreign key relationship between 'message' and 'product' in the schema 'public', but no matches were found.", "hint": "Perhaps you meant 'product_request' instead of 'product'.", "message": "Could not find a relationship between 'message' and 'product' in the schema cache" }`

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase .from("message") .select("*, product_request(*, product(*))");
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip but i resolved using Prisma client to perform query.